# ChartJS remove hover halo / shadow in doughnut chart

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have a customized doughnut chart done in ChartJS and the default hover behaviour is to change color of the hovered arc and show gray halo behind it.

I would like to remove the halo effect, but still be able to change color onHover.

Can someone direct me to the attribute responsible for the halo?

I was able to change hoverBackgroundColor to the one I want, but I cannot find the option responsible for the shadow.

I tried with custom plugin, but still do not know what value should be changed to get rid of the halo.

I also tried with `events: {hover: null}`, but this disabled changing the color as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the halo effect is made through changing `borderColor` on hover.

Setting the value of `hoverBorderColor` to the value same as canvas background  solved my issue.